# How do you bulk update issues in YouTrack?

Tags: youtrack

In Youtrack I would like to move all open issues from one sprint into a new sprint.

Can I bulk update issues using the command dialog? Or do I have to click on all the issues individually to update their sprint values?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28315502/1499016) I was able to move multiple issues from one sprint to another. Adding step by step incase it helps anyone else.

1. Filter all the open, in progress, blocked and submitted issues with the following command: `Sprint: {oldSprint} State: Submitted State: Open State: {In Progress} State: Blocked`
2. On the issue list select all the issues - thanks Alex
3. Click the command dialog button in the header, and select open command dialog.
4. In the command dialog type `Sprint Unscheduled Sprint newSprint`**. This'll first unassign the issue from the old sprint then assign it to the new sprint.

** **Important note**: On newer YouTrack versions, the command is `Sprints`, the full command would be `Sprints Unscheduled Sprints newSprint`.

Comment: Had the same problem, and I think that there is a slight error in your answer. To remove a sprint from command issue list you need to: `remove Sprint Name`. Could you edit this into your answer

Comment: Youtrack 7.0 not detecting the command "Sprint". What is the alternative?

Comment: Can this process be automated somehow ? Meaning: One a sprint is over is  there a way that all the unresolved issue be transfered to the next sprint, or else available in the backlog, so they can be assign to the new sprint ?

Comment: ""You can choose to move all unresolved issues from the current Sprint to the next one"" This is in the advertisement of the product. Hence it would be nice to know how that work in an explicit way

Comment: Also note you should not use Youtrack Lite UI for that. The buttons and checkboxes are missing.

Answer (score 5):

On issue list, you can select multiple issues issues and apply a command to all of them.

Comment: Thanks  I was trying to do this from the agile board! Didn't think about trying from the issue list.

Comment: I think the important point here is, If issue are not resolved in a sprint, they should be available in the backlog for planning right before the next sprint. This will allow to decide what to do with those issues. Because why may plan to resolve some of them two spring down the road or on the next sprint. So the solution mentioned here i believe is a bad solution. Hence if indeed there is no way to automate that process

Comment: i think the best is to have a prepared command to remove the sprint assignment of all the unresolved issue of the last sprint, so that they become available in the backlog again for planning

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this from an agile board, by selecting multiple issues and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to get a command window to act on all of them at once. Then fill in your command, such as the one given in @Paul. B's answer to do what you wish with them!